# Calling a method from adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-adapter, firebaseui

I have the following Code:

```
public static FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;

private void loadList() {

    Query query = db.collection("x").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("x");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
            .setQuery(query, Note.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteViewHolder>(response) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position, Note model) {
            final Note note = notesList.get(position);

            holder.title.setText(note.getTitle());
            holder.content.setText(note.getContent());
            if (note.getNote_image_url() != null) {
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(note.getNote_image_url()).into(holder.bg_note_image);
                holder.bg_note_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    updateNote(note);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note_view, parent, false);
            return new NoteViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return notesList.size();
        }

        public void removeItem(int position) {
            notesList.remove(position);
            // notify the item removed by position
            // to perform recycler view delete animations
            // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

        public void restoreItem(Note item, int position) {
            notesList.add(position, item);
            // notify item added by position
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

SO, a simple FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. But now I need to call the removeItemMethod inside the adapter. But how to do this?

I tried something like this, but all that didn't work.

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
  adapter.removeItem(position);
}
```

I am sitting so long on this Problem. I hope anywhere is a solution to my Problem.

Thanks in advance.
~mb

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga error: cannot find symbol method removeItem(int)

Comment: From where are you calling it?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Outside the adapter. In my case from onSwiped.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ah, I get it. You get this message because the original FirestoreRecyclerAdapter does not have this method. You should create a separate class extending FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and use it when creating an adapter.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Ah great. Have you an example of how the class should look in the end? When not its okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this message because the original FirestoreRecyclerAdapter does not have this method. You should create a separate class extending FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and use it when creating an adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteViewHolder> {

public List<Notes> notesList;

    public MyAdapter(List<Notes> notes, FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response) {
    super(response);
    notesList = notes;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position, 
        Note model) {
        final Note note = notesList.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(note.getTitle());
        holder.content.setText(note.getContent());
        if (note.getNote_image_url() != null) {
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(note.getNote_image_url()).into(holder.bg_note_image);
            holder.bg_note_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateNote(note);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note_view, parent, false);
        return new NoteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notesList.size();
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        notesList.remove(position);
        // notify the item removed by position
        // to perform recycler view delete animations
        // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreItem(Note item, int position) {
        notesList.add(position, item);
        // notify item added by position
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
}
```

Something like this. And when you create an adapter :

```
public static MyAdapter adapter;
```

And initialising it:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(response)
```

Also, it is not a good idea to keep an adapter static.

Edit: pass the items - notesList - in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how I set these Options to my Adapter? `Query query = db.collection("x").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("x");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
            .setQuery(query, Note.class)
            .build();`

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: It says `There is no default constructor available in 'com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` at codeline: `public MyAdapter(List<Notes> notes, FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response) {
    /// set values
    }` .::. And sorry that I am asking so stupid but what do you mean with pass the items - notesList - in the constructor ? Thanks for the tip that I should cancel the static from the adapter.

Comment: Oh right, you should pass the response to the original class by super(response) in the constructor.

As for passed items - in your example you use the list of items in the adapter from parent class. So in your custom adapter create member variable and assign it the value to it from the constructor. I will edit the answer now.

Comment: Wow, okay thank you. But one more problem in this Line `adapter = new NoteListAdapter(response)`. Error:`NoteListAdapter
(java.util.List<com.raycroud.notes.notes.model.Note>,
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note>)
in NoteListAdapter cannot be applied
to
(com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions<com.raycroud.notes.notes.model.Note>)
`

Comment: The constuctor you created in MyAdapter two values are passed - list of notes and response, but while creating the adapter you are passing only response. Just make it:
    new NoteListAdapter(notesList, response);

And please upvote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. StackOverflow needs more people like you. I can't upvote your Answer because under 15 reputation points. So thank you for your help.

Comment: I have a Question. Sure I can't handle this without a separate class? And again thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course you can use internal class like you did it before, but it is a good practice to divide everything to separate classes - the code will be cleaner and easier testable. And there are no drawbacks to it.

Comment: So can you please show me how to solve my problem without an extra class? That would be great. :)

Comment: Actually it is not possible. There is no way to call a custom method from original adapter class. What is wrong with the separate class?

Comment: At the moment I have a problem. And with a not separated adapter class the error would be fixed.

Comment: Please give more info, I only see drawbacks in using internal class. I am sure it can be solved with having new class.

Comment: Yes sure it could be solved without an integrated class, but the error comes since that change. And I don't know where the Error is because it is a `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Size 0, Index 0` with no specific line.

Comment: In the log there should be a line in blue, this is line of your code. This error means that the list you are passing has no entries, it tries to get first entry (0) while there are no entries available. It has nothing to do with internal or external classes

Comment: I know that it hasn't to do anything with that. But before that, it worked. And I am working at this problem a long time with no success. Yes, i know the problem, but no specific line. So its impossible to find the errorline. Wait, I know what could help me. Do you know a full example from google or any other websites with an external adapter.

Comment: Well each adapter is a bit individual due to it's data list. Could you post your activity code with whole crash log in https://pastebin.com/ and paste the url here?

Comment: Okay I uploaded snippets of my project into my dropbox. There is the Error and the other Activities. When you have a problem to download let me know, but I think everything should work fine. Can you please look at my files? Maybe I am too stupid to find the IndexOutOfBoundsException. But I am so desperately because I work so long at this error with no success. Here is the link to the files:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hqrmzubd4tjzd8p/AAAZtwCkw0sodaKssZ6JEQgpa?dl=0

Comment: Is the error thrown before the application starts and is shown? Or on some action?

Comment: I don't know the application opens and stuff, like Toolbar, FloatingActionButton loads. Then the error comes. The only thing that doesn't load is the recyclerview.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find a problem. To be honest, because your classes do not have separate classes and even methods, your code is hard to read. It would be perfect if any class would be less than 100 lines. I have never worked with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter, but I assume that there is some issue with data. I see that firestoreListener = `db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes")` but in it's callback I see `Query query = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes");` My guess is that you don't need `firestoreListener` , but set it on the adapter

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. The thing with the `firestoreListener` I update later. Now can you please look the last time at MainActivity.java at my dropbox? I reduced my code to the important snippets. Maybe you see something.

Comment: Activity is something like https://pastebin.com/embed_js/fAHi8UE7 and adapter is wrong as well. I have checked firebase ui examples a bit and I see that they do it differently: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database

Comment: I guess the biggest difference between the examples and your code is filtering function, you have to find other way to filter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will have a look at it.

Comment: But at GitHub they use the Adapter in Mainactivity too. :(

Comment: True, but they dont have extra methods, remove and restore items. Firebase adapter is helpful when you want to load items from firestore on demand, while scrolling list. If you dont need that, you can get all the items once and use simple adapter.